# Sending email via PHP error

Tags: php, email

im a php beginner, and I am building a website, and website is supposed to let people send me email. the thing is i never knew anything about sending emails through php. I looked it up online and tried using the codes i found. The thing is my program says it sent the email but i never happen to get the email. I thought maybe it is because I am using apache server to test my php, and maybe it is gona work when I upload it to a real server??(yes this was a question)

Just in case, this is my code, and it is the all php code in my website, also form works fine, there is nothing wrong with it.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = "From: " . $_POST['name'] . ", " . $_POST['email'] . "\n Message: " .    $_POST['message'];
try {
    mail("serdarufuk95@gmail.com", $subject, $message, " ");
    unset($_POST['name']);
    header("Location: success.php");

}
catch (PDOException $e)
{

    include 'index.html';
    exit();
}
exit();

} 
include 'contact2.php';

?>
```

is there a problem with the code? or do i have to call something from a library or anything or am i missing a code! HELP ME MAKE THIS WORK! when i execute it, it takes me to success.php, so i assumed nothing is wrong with my code, but you guys know better!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266204/php-mail-function-does-not-work-on-web-host

Comment: What's a `PDOException` doing there?

Comment: `mail()` doesn't throw exceptions. It just returns a boolean FALSE on failure. PHP may support objects, but it is not OOP in and of itself. No core PHP function will throw an exception, but many of the add-on libraries do, e.g. PDO or mysqli.

Comment: Thanks guys for not giving solutions but telling me mail() doesnt throw exceptions -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not work after uploading to a real server if the server's mail configuration has not been set yet. So I suggest you to use a better and simpler version in order to send mails through PHP: **PHPMailer**

```
require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->AddAddress("mail@domain.com","Display name");
$mail->Subject= "Mail subject";
$mail->Body= "Mail content";

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "mail.domain.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "formmail@domain.com";
$mail->Password = "123456";
$mail->IsHTML(true); //true if you want to send html content. false for plain text message
$mail->From = $_POST['Email'];
$mail->FromName = $_POST['Name'];
$mail->Send();
```

You may download the class [clicking here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php4/PHPMailer%20v2.0.4%20for%20PHP4/PHPMailer_v2.0.4.zip/download?use_mirror=garr&r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fphpmailer%2Ffiles%2Fphpmailer%2520for%2520php4%2F&use_mirror=garr)

Comment: thanks man, ill try this one. This is the only answer that gives me solution.

Comment: It will work with Apache, assuming you have configured a *mail transfer agent,* which is way beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @user2864414 as acobster said it will work on apache. Trt my way

Comment: @user2864414 if my answer fixed your problem, please sign it as answer, so other people who will encounter the same problem can easily get the answwer.